# For next to add with classic asp

Tags: for-loop, asp-classic

for the next "A to Z" getting results.
for into; 5 and the number 6, I want to add.
How do I make.

```
for k = asc("A") to asc("Z")
response.write chr(k)
next
```

Result :

A
B
C
..
Z

I want
A
B
C
..
Z
5
6

Such as `( k = asc("A") to asc("Z") add "5" and add"6" )`

Comment: This question confuses me. Are you asking how to iterate through the alphabet or from 97 to 90? Also what are you adding "5" and "6" to, is it to k?

Comment: I want to add 2 more cycles. Variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really have a loop for this, just add separate commands:

```
for k = asc("A") to asc("Z")
    response.write chr(k)
next
response.write "5"
response.write "6"
```

Another option is storing all the ASCII numbers in array then looping that array:

```vbs
Dim arrLetters(), x
ReDim arrLetters(-1)
For k=Asc("A") To Asc("Z")
    ReDim Preserve arrLetters(UBound(arrLetters) + 1)
    arrLetters(UBound(arrLetters)) = k
Next
ReDim Preserve arrLetters(UBound(arrLetters) + 1)
arrLetters(UBound(arrLetters)) = Asc("5")
ReDim Preserve arrLetters(UBound(arrLetters) + 1)
arrLetters(UBound(arrLetters)) = Asc("6")
For x=0 To UBound(arrLetters)
    k = arrLetters(x)
    response.write chr(k)
Next
Erase arrLetters
```

Comment: Hi shadow, OK, but I'm having another operation in the loop. outside the loop again to make a transaction, the system will be tired. 
for k = asc("A") to asc("Z")
  char (k) related to other process ....
next

Comment: thank you shadow. But; 5-6 does not appear. response.write chr(k) result: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

Answer (score 0):

```
strString = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ56"
For i=1 To Len(strString)
    Response.Write Mid(strString,i,1)
Next
```